# Gradle sync failed: support-core-utils

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, synchronization, android-support-library

I'm dealing with Android project sync.

The error I get is always the same:

> Failed to resolve: support-core-utils
>
> Failed to resolve: support-compat

Currently, my repositories are:

```
maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools/' }
maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/firebase/gradle/' }
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
google()
jcenter {url 'https://firebase.bintray.com/gradle'}
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: maybe related to : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120759347  (lots of issues with android libraries resolution these days, due to this issue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to move `google()` to top of others like this

```
google()
maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools/' }
maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/firebase/gradle/' }
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
jcenter {url 'https://firebase.bintray.com/gradle'}
```

Comment: I just tried this, but the problem persists! Any other suggestion?